# the wso2 soa security gateway solution

Tags: wso2, ws-security, wso2-api-manager

I found a white paper [the wso2 soa security gateway solution](http://wso2.com/whitepapers/wso2-security-and-identity-gateway-solution/) that builds a security gateway for SOA.

and in [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) Home page it says that:

> It leverages proven, production-ready integration, security, and
>   governance components from the WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus, WSO2
>   Identity Server, and WSO2 Governance Registry. In addition, it
>   leverages the WSO2 Business Activity Monitor for Big Data analytics,
>   giving you instant insight into APIs behavior.

my question is: Does WSO2 API Manager do every thing mentioned in whitepaper document? if yes why the whitepaper is written? can we use WSO2 API Manager as an XML Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given white paper has been published in 2011 and WSO2 API manger is resealed later 2012 and it is improving with the industry standards. All most all the aspects were covered in latest [WSO2 API manger (v 1.7)](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/).

You can make use of WSO2 API manger or WSO2 ESB for XML Gateway.